# Chart.js plot not aligned with xAxis labels

Tags: chart.js, vue-chartjs

I have the following Scatter plot chart created with Chart.js and for some reason, the green dots are not aligned with the xAxis labels. Note that I am doing this in a Vue.js app using vue-chart.js but I don't think this is the reason. Any idea of how I could align plots and xAxis labels?

[image]

```
data: {
  labels: this.sessionLabels, // Example: ["2020-02-07T13:57:43", "2020-02-07T13:57:43", "2020-02-07T13:57:43", "2020-02-07T13:57:43", "2020-02-07T16:42:39", "2020-02-07T16:42:39"...]
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "Session",
      backgroundColor: "#42b983",
      data: this.sessions // Example: [{x:1, y:0}, {x:2, y:0}, {x:3, y:0}, ...]
    }
  ]
},
options: {
  title: {
    display: true,
    text: "Sessions executed over the last 7 days",
    fontColor: "#ffffff",
    fontSize: "14",
    fontStyle: "normal"
  },
  legend: {
    display: false
  },
  scales: {
    xAxes: [
      {
        ticks: {
          callback: function(value, index, values) {
            return this.sessionLabelsAlias[index];
          }.bind(this)
        }
      }
    ],
    yAxes: [
      {
        ticks: {
          max: 100,
          min: 0,
          stepSize: 10
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problems is that your `sessionLabels` contains identical values.

Also when explicitly defining `labels`, your data should simply be an array of values, each one corresponding to the label at the same position.

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ...]
```